# Checking for value within boundaries

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a function that would verify if a value is within chosen boundaries and if it's not, the user must retry until verification.

I wanted to know why my code skips the if condition for any given value and it returns me for the input prompt : *"Error: Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other syntax error."*

`A=limit(5pi/6,-pi/2,pi/2)` for example jumps directly to the else condition while it's *true* for the if condition

Here is my code :

```
function alpha = limit(pos,min,max)

 if (pos >= max) && (pos <= min) 
     alpha=pos;
 else
     while pos >= max || pos <= min 
        prompt = 'Enter value between max and min';
        alpha = input(prompt);
    end 
 end

end
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @FangQ My bad sorry. It isn't working at all, it just skips the if condition for any given value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function first checks whether `pos` is **both** greater than or equal to `max` **and** less than or equal to `min`.

I expect you intend `max` to be greater than `min`. Therefore, the `if` line should be:

`if (pos <= max) && (pos >= min)`

I assume your `val_max`/`val_min` are typos (and should be `max`/`min`) Then, your `while` loop depends on the value of `pos`. But `pos` is never updated in the loop, so your loop is just going to iterate forever.

You need to update `pos` inside the `while` loop for this to work. Try something like this:

```
function alpha = limit(pos,min,max)

    while pos > max || pos < min 
        prompt = 'Enter value between min and max';
        pos = input(prompt);
    end 

    alpha = pos;

end
```